# Reading a combination without confirming with enter?

Tags: c++

So basically I just want to read characters from the user and make my code know that when user types a defined combination (say, CTRL+F - but without confirming with Enter, for exmaple), it's the end of the input. How can I do that? I only know how to read characters with enter and comparing their ASCII's...

Comment: Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, Windows.

Comment: can it be ended by a specific character?

Comment: Under linux, CTRL+D is the end of input. You don't have to do anything. Just write something like `while (input != EOF)`. Under windows the combination is CTRL+Z.

Comment: Yep but I have to confirm it with enter anyway. And what I'd like to do is to catch it without making the user confirm.

Comment: Console or GUI program?

Comment: Console. Sorry again... :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT
Reading through your question again, I realize that I misinterpreted your question. I'll leave this since it might still be useful to you or others.

---

What you're asking for doesn't have to do much with reading characters. In fact, CTRL is not a character at all. You're basically just checking for key pushes. Handling this kind of input is platform dependent, and even on a single platform, multiple methods will exist. One way to do it for windows is by using `GetAsyncKeyState`. This function will check whether a specified key is being pushed right now. Note that it doesn't 'remember' input, so you'll have to check this function many times per second to register all user input.

You supply the function with a single argument specifying the key of which you want to check the state. A list of all key codes can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Example:

```
#include <iostream> //for output
#include <windows.h> //for GetAsyncKeyState

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) ) //CTRL-key is pressed
        {
            if( GetAsyncKeyState( 0x46 ) ) //F-key is pressed
                std::cout << "CTRL-F is pressed" << std::endl;
            if( GetAsyncKeyState( 0x58 ) ) //X-key is pressed
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "CTRL-X was pressed, stopping.." << std::endl;
}
```

This example will continuously check if `CTRL-F` is being pushed and if so write output, until `CTRL-X` is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     bool keepGoing = true;
     char key = ' ';
     while (keepGoing){
       cout << "Enter a key" << endl;
       while(_kbhit()){
         key = _getch();
         cout << "You entered: " << key << endl;
       }
     }
}
```

then specify delimiter when to end loop.

if on linux curses are available. there is also a getch function. you should use curses if you aim for cross platform compatibility. ncurses library functions are similar to ones in conio.h.
[ncurses tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Comment: And which header file provides the _kbhit() and _getch()?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows system call [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28VS.85%29.aspx) allows you to read console input directly. You may want to wrap that call into a function that just extracts the essential data from the several parameters of the `ReadConsoleInput` function. You can write a function to check if there is any input using [`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).